# Find strings after search in txt file

Tags: python

I wondering if sombody could help me withth e following resolve the following code:

I have a text-file called report.txt with following content (everything is the same line):

```
Printed: 2013-07-12 05:09 PM QC Product: PROT2 CON Level: Level 3 Priority: QC Method RF Result 174 IU/mL Lot Number: 3BQH01 Sample ID: 3BQH01 Instrument ID: DV330681 QC Range 158.0 - 236.0 Comment Completed: 2013-07-12 17:09:14 Comment: Trigger: Manual Trigger Operator C160487AUR Time of Run 2013-07-12 17:09:14 Reagent 13049MA
```

Now need to retrieve following information ( only the values after the : )

```
QC Product: PROT2 CON
Level: Level 3
Sample ID: 3BQH01
```

I was trying the following code:

```
with open ('report.txt', 'r') as inF:
        for line in inF:
            if 'Sample ID:' in line:           
                SID = line.split(':')[1].strip()
            if 'Level:' in line:           
                LEV = line.split(':')[1].strip()                    
            if 'QC Product:' in line:           
                QCP = line.split(':')[1].strip()
```

does anybody has an idea or an other solution?

Thanks a lot for all your efforts and help,

Kindly regards
Koen

Comment: "an idea" for what? Your indentation is wrong, maybe just here but if in your code that will be a problem.

Comment: First of all thanks for "restructure" my request. Indeed I think also that I need to look for an other method, do you have any idea?

Comment: Do you have any control over the contents of the report.txt file?  It would be a lot easier to do what you're doing if you had some kind of delimiters between the fields, such as a separation character or line break.Assuming that's not possible, could you provide a few examples of those files?  Inferring how the format might vary from line to line or from file to file is kind of difficult from just one example.

Comment: Hello Mark, unfortunately I have no influence on the layout of the file it self. The positions are text are fixed as well only the values are changing...

Comment: But you can say if the items 'Printed','QC Product','Level','Priority',etc are always in this order of succession, can't you ?

Comment: Yes indeed they are always in the same order ... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

s = ('Printed: 2013-07-12 05:09 PM '
     'QC Product: PROT2 CON '
     'Level: Level 3 '
     'Priority: QC Method RF '
     'Result 174 IU/mL '
     'Lot Number: 3BQH01 '
     'Sample ID: 3BQH01 '
     'Instrument ID: DV330681 '
     'QC Range 158.0 - 236.0 '
     'Comment Completed: 2013-07-12 17:09:14 '
     'Comment: Trigger: Manual Trigger '
     'Operator C160487AUR '
     'Time of Run 2013-07-12 17:09:14 '
     'Reagent 13049MA')

rgx = re.compile('QC Product *: *(.+?)(?<=\S) +'
                 'Level *: *(.+?)(?<=\S) +'
                 'Priority *:.+?'
                 'Sample ID *: *(.+?)(?<=\S) +'
                 'Instrument ID')

print rgx.search(s).groups()
```

But this code supposes that the items are always ordred in the same succession

Comment: Thanks a lot for this piece of code, the order is always the same, one more small question, I need put each field to each piece to a ceperated string (ex. QCproduct=...)is this possible to with re.compile ??

Comment: Could you describe further, please. I don't understand this affair of separated string

Comment: The overall purpose is to rename the file with the values of QC Product, Level and Sample ID ... final = despath + "/" + prefixQ + SID + "_" + LEV + "_" + QCP + date + "_" + ".pdf"

Comment: Test what ``print "{} - {} - {}".format(*rgx.search(s).group(2,2,3))`` and ``print "{} - {} - {}".format(*rgx.search(s).group(2,1,3))`` give as results, and conclude yourself how you can use ``group()`` and ``format()`` to obtain what you want.

Comment: I replaced  all the parts ``(.+?)(?<=\S) *`` with ``(.+?)(?<=\S) +`` because it is evident that there will always be a blank before **Level**, **Priority** and **Intsrument ID**

Comment: Thanks a lot for resolving this issue... It is now clear for me how to continue...